# GIT download zip between 2 commits

Tags: git

I am trying to download a zip with the changes between 2 commits in my repository, but I get the error that the option `name-only` is unknown for the `git diff` commando.

this is my commando:

```
git archive -o update.zip f7a9d931b889d11bdb07cd232687c4924f963d5a $(git diff --name-only 4874e524062c76b35dc3c9f6b569498a2aa39333)
```

[commits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQEsj.png)

Comment: A `zip` with the changes? Export a diff and zip it?

Comment: @tkausl how do I do this i use bitbucket

Comment: [format-patch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch), for example. Or just `git diff > changes.txt`.

Comment: I want the actual files that have been updated not just an overview of the diff

Comment: FYI, a commit contains all files in a repo, not just the ones which have changed.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this issue is caused by windows CMDER.
The commando works fine if I run it with Powershell.

cmder github issue:
https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/318